# Create columns containing the quantile() function output

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to create multiple columns based on the `quantile()` function output. I actually want the quantile of each rows containing womens and mens value.

Example for line 1 : 
I want `quantile(c(4.6, 5.8))`
Which give :

```
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 4.6  4.9  5.2  5.5  5.8
```

Here is a sample of data and the output I want :

**data :**

```
  code  womens  mens
1: 01    4.6    5.8
2: 02    5.0    4.6
3: 03    4.1    5.3
4: 04    5.2    3.0
5: 05    4.6    5.4
6: 06    2.3    3.4
```

**what I want :**

```
  code  womens  mens  0%  25%  50%  75% 100%
1: 01    4.6    5.8  4.6  4.9  5.2  5.5  5.8 
2: 02    5.0    4.6  4.6  4.7  4.8  4.9  5.0   
3: 03    4.1    5.3  4.1  4.4  4.7  5.0  5.3
4: 04    5.2    3.0  3.0  3.5  4.1  4.6  5.2 
5: 05    4.6    5.4  4.6  4.8  5.0  5.2  5.4 
6: 06    2.3    3.4  2.3  2.6  2.8  3.1  3.4
```

I already tried with `lapply()` and some `for loop` without results. The result I had was always the same `4.6  4.9  5.2  5.5  5.8` for every rows.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `data.table`, one option in `base R`, would be to convert to `data.frame` (`setDF`), then loop through the rows with `apply` (`MARGIN = 1`), get the `quantile`s and assign new columns

```
library(data.table)
setDF(df1)
df1[c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")] <- t(apply(df1[, 2:3], 1, 
           quantile, na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(code = 1:6, womens = c(4.6, 5, 4.1, 5.2, 4.6, 
2.3), mens = c(5.8, 4.6, 5.3, 3, 5.4, 3.4)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you I think its gonna work but I have some NAs (in the full dt) how do I add the ``na.rm = TRUE`` in your code? I tried after quantile but got  error in bmerge.

Comment: df1[,c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")] <- apply(df1[, 2:3], 1, quantile)

Comment: I think you need a **","** in the "[,]"

Comment: @Tedel  The `quantile` have `na.rm` argument.  So you can use that

Comment: @akrun that's how I tried the na.rm = TRUE but it return me the following error : Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  typeof x.rls (double) != typeof i.V1 (character)

Comment: @Tedel  Do you have a data.table.  In that case, use `with = FALSE` while subsetting

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot for your answer, it works! You're the best, always giving the best answer thanks again! I will accept the answer when stack allow me too.

Comment: @akrun last thing, why are the results different. If I do ``quantile(c(4.6, 5.8))`` I get : 4.6  4.9  5.2  5.5  5.8 but with the full function the first line is :  4.6 4.9 4.7 4.3  4.8
 instead ?

Comment: @Tedel  When I tried `t(apply(df1[, 2:3], 1, quantile,  na.rm = TRUE))
      0%   25%  50%   75% 100%
[1,] 4.6 4.900 5.20 5.500  5.8`  Could that be possible because when you tried the object as a data.fable first and then changed some values?

Comment: strange the code you provide me work just fine but the one in the answer gives me different values, I'll take a look at my data, thanks again! Edit : yes I actually simply did ``as.data.frame()`` the error must come from this

Comment: @Tedel  Forgot the `transpose` i..e `t`.  Fixed it

Answer (score 3):

```
cbind(d, do.call(rbind, lapply(1:NROW(d), function(i){
    quantile(d[i, c("womens", "mens")])
})))
#   code womens mens  0%   25%  50%   75% 100%
#1:    1    4.6  5.8 4.6 4.900 5.20 5.500  5.8
#2:    2    5.0  4.6 4.6 4.700 4.80 4.900  5.0
#3:    3    4.1  5.3 4.1 4.400 4.70 5.000  5.3
#4:    4    5.2  3.0 3.0 3.550 4.10 4.650  5.2
#5:    5    4.6  5.4 4.6 4.800 5.00 5.200  5.4
#6:    6    2.3  3.4 2.3 2.575 2.85 3.125  3.4
```

**DATA**

```
d = structure(list(code = 1:6,
                   womens = c(4.6, 5, 4.1, 5.2, 4.6, 2.3),
                   mens = c(5.8, 4.6, 5.3, 3, 5.4, 3.4)),
              class = "data.frame",
              row.names = c("1:", "2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:"))
```